# My go web server won't build when I do go build, it says package is not in goroot (or gopath) everytime

Tags: go

I have a go server repository then cloned it to linux system in folder /var/www/develop/project.id.
It has several folders with each folders have their own go file(s).
The main.go is located in folder/subfolder/main.go.
In each go files, if I need to import go files from another folder, I do:

```
import myproject/foldername/subfoldername
```

Then in the root project, I do:

```
go mod init myproject
go mod tidy
go build -o main folder/subfolder/main.go
```

But I failed at the build step because package myproject/foldername/subfoldername is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/myproject/foldername/subfoldername).

Any help on solving this problem?
Thank you.

UPDATE: I lose my mind, I can’t make it work. It works everywhere else (on windows) but it’s just not work for this particular project (multiple folders same inside) on Linux but it works on a different project.

Comment: please include your go version!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the go.mod file.  Run the command `go mod init myproject` to create the go.mod file.  Notice that `mod` and `init` are swapped in the command that you ran.

Comment: I did that. It's still does not work. My problem is still in go build step with the same error.

Answer (score -1):

every files like xx.go always need 'main.go',unless 'go build' it separated.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).